# Regex Match a word exactly n times on a query parameter for use with rewritecond .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like some help please. I would like to match a condition from the http referer in the htaccess file within a wordpress website. I want to pass a query parameter from the 'referer' to the request uri

I'm trying to use the mod_rewrite function to do this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^((?!menu=a.*\&menu=a).)*$ 
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

I want to match the following

```
http://example.co.uk?menu=a&menu=a false
http://couldbeanything.co.uk?couldbeanything=b&menu=a true
http://example.co.uk?tile=b&menu=a true
http://example.co.uk/?menu=a true
http://example.co.uk/?menu false
http://example.co.uk/testing123/?tile=a&menu=a true
http://example.co.uk false
http://example.co.uk/?p=12 false
http://example.co.uk/?p=12&menu=a&menu=a false
http://example.co.uk/?p=12&menu=a&tile=b&menu=a false
```

I want to be able to match on the query parameter when it occurs once and once only. I dont want to match on zero occurrences. I do not want to match on two or more occurrences.

I have tried

```
^((?!menu=a.*\&menu=a).)*$
```

I have tried

```
.*?.*(menu=){1}
```

I have tried

```
^(?!.*menu=.*menu=).+$
```

I have tried

```
^(?!(.*menu=){1})(.*menu=){1}.*$
```

All of the above are not quite exactly what I need. I have tried a lot of different regexs.

I thought I could try and  inversing matching which I saw in another post and then somehow manipulating this in the htaccess so i tried this but couldn't match properly either.

```
^((?!menu).)*$
```

I feel like I might be approaching this from the wrong angle and this might not be what regex is for.

Maybe I could do a count matching on 
`menu=somevariable`
and manipulate that from the htaccess file? I couldn't find information on google search how to do this.

Any input on how to solve this would be much appreciated. I dont mind if it's not in regex as long as it's doable in the htaccess file.

Thanks for any input.

Further Update after finding correct regex

I have tried this but I'm getting erratic behaviour from the site as the query is added repeatedly to the request uri.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*(menu=)).*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(?!.*\menu=\b.*\bmenu=\b).*\bmenu=\b.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}?menu=a [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I found out that google chrome strips the referer tag from the request so it is not possible to use the method above reliably without making clients use a different browser which is unenforceable.

I used an alternative method which was to take the url parameter from the slug then store a cookie and use the cookie to do the redirect.

Code to get copy/pasted or wp created slug

```
function get_slug_param( $slugname ) {
// Initialize the slug param value
$slug = null;

$queryURL = parse_url( html_entity_decode( esc_url( add_query_arg( $arr_params ) ) ) );
parse_str( $queryURL['query'], $getVar );
$slug = $getVar[$slugname];

return $slug;
```

}

Code to set cookie

```
$cookieName = 'whitechocolate';
$cookieValue = '2';
unset( $_COOKIE[$cookieName]);
setcookie($cookieName, $cookieValue, time() + (86400 * 30), '/' ); // set to a day
```

Code to do redirect from cookie

```
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])) {
    //echo "dont use echo to output html before php otherwise parsing error will php occur";
    //use the value from the cookie to add to the query arg
    $changeurl = add_query_arg($cookieName, $_COOKIE[$cookieName], get_permalink());
    header('Location: '.$changeurl);
}
```